# Maximum value of a list according to another list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `res2` and `Cb`. I want to print maximum value according to an operation as shown below but I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
res2=[3, 4, 6]
Cb=[[0,10,20,30,40,50,60]]

for i in range(0,len(res2)):
    Max=max(Cb[0][res2[i]])
    print(Max)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    Max=max(Cb[0][res2[i]])

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The expected output is

```
60
```

Comment: Can you clarify the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to slice `Cb[0]` with `res2`, then get the max.

You could use:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res2 = [3, 4, 6]
Cb = [[0,10,20,30,40,50,60]]

out = max(itemgetter(*res2)(Cb[0]))
```

Or:

```
out = max(Cb[0][i] for i in res2)
```

Output: `60`